# Webix: total accordion collapse via one button

Tags: javascript, accordion, webix

First of all, I'm a newbie to Webix and javascript.

Using Webix, can I collapse all accordion items by clicking the button? 
ID's of items are defined as string values.
Sure i can write something like this:

```
$$("1").collapse();
$$("2").collapse();
$$("3").collapse();
...
$$("33").collapse();
```

But it seems "a little" unhandy. Here's the short snippet.

http://webix.com/snippet/748d84ac

I'll appreciate if anyone could explain if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getChildViews` API to get all accordion panels, and close them like next

```
var cells = $$("acc_cl").getChildViews();
for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++){
    cells[i].collapse();
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/a462e807